# Normalizing multilevel json string that's contained in a list

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm having issues trying to flatten a json string into a pandas data frame cleanly. When I use json_normalize, I get the first parent 'id' as a column, and the rest of the string is within the second column. The second column is a list with each element with a multilevel string.

I'm not sure how to cleanly flatten this string without having to create a solution that can loop through and bind each level into a dataframe.

Here is the API URL: https://api.collegefootballdata.com/games/players?year=2018&week=1&seasonType=regular

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import json

base = 'https://api.collegefootballdata.com/'
end_point = 'games/players?year='
second_end_point = '&week='
third_end_point = '&seasonType=regular'

request = requests.get(base + end_point + str(2018) + second_end_point + str(1) + third_end_point).text
json_dict = json.loads(request)
normalize_df = json_normalize(json_dict)
print(normalize_df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this as a starter and modify it to suit your needs:

```
pd.io.json.json_normalize(json_dict, ['teams', 'categories', 'types', 'athletes'], meta=[
    ['teams', 'school'],
    ['teams', 'categories', 'name'],
    ['teams', 'categories', 'types', 'name']
])
```

Result:

```
        id               name stat teams.school teams.categories.name teams.categories.types.name
0  3115980  Lawrence Marshall    0     Michigan             defensive                          PD
1  4360699         Myles Sims    0     Michigan             defensive                          PD
2  4046537      Josh Metellus    0     Michigan             defensive                          PD
3  4046525     Khaleke Hudson    0     Michigan             defensive                          PD
4  3115968     Brandon Watson    0     Michigan             defensive                          PD
5  4258211     J'Marick Woods    0     Michigan             defensive                          PD
6  4046526          Devin Gil    0     Michigan             defensive                          PD
7  4046536         David Long    0     Michigan             defensive                          PD
8  4046523        Rashan Gary    0     Michigan             defensive                          PD
9  4258198          Josh Ross    0     Michigan             defensive                          PD
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you so much its taken me hours of trying and testing and I couldnt even get this far.